# How to Moq a Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I currently have a function that creates an array of **responses**. As you can see in my code down below I am running a **Task.WhenAll** this will grab each object in my arrayOfRequests and run it through my **FunctionThatCreatesResponse** returning the response for **EACH** object in the **arrayOfRequests**

```
var arrayOfRequests = new [] { RequestObject1, RequestObject2, RequestObject3 }
var arrayOfResponses = await Task.WhenAll(arrayOfRequests.Select(req => FunctionThatCreatesResponse(req)));

private async Task<ResponseObject> FunctionThatCreatesResponse(RequestObject req)
{
    // The response will be created here and returned
}
```

How can I mock the *task.WhenAll()* to return a pre defined **arrayOfResponses**?

Something along the lines of:

```
var task = new Mock<Task>();
task.Setup(t => t.WhenAll()).ReturnsAsync(arrayOfResponses);
```

Comment: Would Task.FromResult be an option?

Comment: @SirRufo How would you mock it though? Could you provide an example of your train of thought?

Comment: You need to show more code that is being tested, right now it does not make sense what you are trying to do with your test. For example you need to show us where RequestObject1, RequestObject2, and RequestObject3 came from, or you need to mock `arrayOfResponses` itself. That is the spot you need to mock, not the Task.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I want to mock the Task.WhenAll so it will return an array of response objects when I run my test.

Comment: In that case pass it in a IEnumerable of ResposeObjects, you can't mock the task, but you can mock what gets passed in

Comment: @Lostaunaum `FunctionThatCreatesResponse` or what ever is within that function is what needs to be exposed to be able to mock the return from the Task. The `Task.WenAll` will perform its designed function once provided with the correct data.

Comment: @Nkosi that is an internal method that only gets called within that function. I am guessing there is really no way of "mocking" the Task. The only solution for this would be to expose **FunctionThatCreatesResponse** and mocking the parent class so that whenver that function is called the array I want is returned. That is not what I needed but I guess there is no other way around it.

Comment: @Lostaunaum that is correct.

Comment: @Nkosi i will take that as a valid answer if you want to post it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FunctionThatCreatesResponse` or what ever is within that function is what needs to be exposed to be able to mock the return from the Task. The `Task.WenAll` will perform its designed function once provided with the correct data.

Based on comment you also indicated

> that is an internal method that only gets called within that function.

an option would be to expose the desired functionality.

```
//A single responsibility abstraction
public interface IClient {
    Task<ResponseObject> CreatesResponse(RequestObject req);
}

public class ExampleClass {
    private readonly IClient client;

    public ExampleClass(IClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseObject[]> GetResponses(RequestObject[] arrayOfRequests){
        var arrayOfResponses = await Task.WhenAll(arrayOfRequests
            .Select(req => client.CreatesResponse(req)));
        return arrayOfResponses;
    }
}
```

So now that the subject under test has been refactored, the method under test can be exercised and its behavior asserted.

```
public async Task ExampleClass_GetResponses_Should_Return_ResponseArray() {
    //Arrange
    var factoryMock = new Mock<IClient>();
    factoryMock.Setup(_ => _.CreatesResponse(It.IsAny<RequestObject>()))
               .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new ResponseObject()));

    var sut = new ExampleClass(factoryMock.Object);
    var arrayOfRequests = new [] { RequestObject1, RequestObject2, RequestObject3 };

    //Act
    var actual = await sut.GetResponses(arrayOfRequests);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    //...assert desired behavior
}
```

The implementation of `IClient` would encapsulate the actual functionality and should be registered at the composition root.